# Minimization of concave function w.r.t. only to some independent variables.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $f(x)$ be a concave function in $\mathcal{C}^2$.

Consider a vector ${\bf y} = [y_1, \ldots, y_N]^\top \in Y = [0, a]^N$, where $a>0$ is a real number.

Finally, for a given $1 \leq k \leq N$, consider the following problem:

$$\left\{y_{k}^*,y_{k+1}^*, \ldots, y_N^*\right\} = \arg \min_{y_{k},y_{k+1}, \ldots, y_N}  f\left(\sum_{i=1}^Ny_i\right)\\
\text{s.t.} \\y_i \in [0, a] ~~\forall 1 \leq i\leq N.
$$

In other words, I should find the values $\left\{y_{k}^*,y_{k+1}^*, \ldots, y_N^*\right\}$ such that:

$$f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} y_i + \sum_{i=k}^N y_i^*\right) \leq f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} y_i + \sum_{i=k}^N y_i\right)$$

for any vector ${\bf y}.$

I'm having difficulties since:

1. We are minimizing a concave function (usually, it is easier to maximize them).
2. The minimization is performed with respect to some independent variables.

My intuition suggests me that the minimum is attained when $$y_k^* = y_{k+1}^* = \ldots = y_N^* = 0.$$

Any suggestion about how to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: In your proposed optimization problem, what are $y_1,\dots,y_{k-1}$? Are they also variables in the model? If so, how does $k$ come into play?

Comment: You say $f$ is $C^2$ but it appears to not have a limit at $0$.

Comment: The sum $\sum_{i=1}^{N}y_i$ is a fixed quantity. So we can look at the behaviour of $f$ at $ x^* = \sum_{i=1}^{N}y_i$. Supposing that $f$ is increasing on a neighbourhood of $x^*$, we would simply find $\{y_i^*\}$ so that $\sum_{i=k}^{N}y_i^*  \geq  \sum_{i=k}^{N}y_i $

Comment: Also I think seeing as you find $\arg \min$, the inequality should swap direction in the last expression.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst there are many errors in my question and also useless information. I'm going to edit it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that the actual values of the first $k$ and the last $N-k$ variables do not matter. What matters is their sum. So, the problem is equivalent to minimizing $f(x + y)$, subject to $x \in [0, ka]$, and $y \in [0, (N-k) a]$ over $y$.

We can make the change of variables $z = x + y$, or equivalently $y = z - x$, meaning that we need to solve
$$
\min_{x \leq z \leq x + (N-k) a)} f(z).
$$
The minimum of a concave function over a convex set is always attained at the extreme points (corners) of the set. The extreme points of the interval $[x, x+(N-k) a]$ are its endpoints, so the minimum is $\min\{ f(x), f(x+(N-k) a \}$.

Overall, 
$$
g(y_1, \dots, y_k) = \min_{y_{k+1}, \dots, y_N} f(\sum_{i=1}^k y_i + \sum_{i=k+1}^N y_i) = \min\left\{ f\left(\sum_{i=1}^k y_i\right), f\left(\sum_{i=1}^k y_i + (N-k) a\right) \right\}
$$

Depending on which endpoint turns out to have smaller value, you have either $y_{k+1}^* = \dots = y_N^* = 0$ or any values which sum up to $(N-k) a$, such as $y_{k+1}^* = \dots = y_N^* = a$.